# I2C interface on Tiva

Tags: c, embedded, arm, microcontroller

On a Tiva (Texas Instruments Cortex M4F ARM) TM4C129XNCZAD I have a problem with I2C interface. I have enabled both a master on I2C module 4 thru port K and a slave on I2C module 6 thru port B. I have interconnected both I2C modules. Using Texas Instruments driver library I tried to send 1 byte using I2C_MASTER_CMD_SINGLE_SEND command. I spend a lot of time to make it working, but SCK line keeps Low logical level. I followed exactly TivaWare™ Peripheral Driver Library USER’S GUIDE, but the communication doesn't work. Has anybody some experience with it?

There is my code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_i2c.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/i2c.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "inc/tm4c129xnczad.h"

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x3C

void  delay  (void)
{
    volatile uint32_t ui32Loop; 
    for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 200000; ui32Loop++);
}

volatile  uint32_t  result;

int  main  (void)
{
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_1 | SYSCTL_USE_OSC | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ); 
    //
    // Enable the GPIO port that is used for the on-board LED.
    //
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R3 | SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R9 | SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R1;
    //
    // Do a dummy read to insert a few cycles after enabling the peripheral.
    //
    result = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R;
    //
    // Enable the GPIO pin for the LED (PD3).  Set the direction as output, and
    // enable the GPIO pin for digital function.
    //
    GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DIR_R = 0x8;
    GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DEN_R = 0x8;
    GPIO_PORTK_DEN_R = 0xC0;        // Enable Port K for I2C module 4

    GPIO_PORTB_AHB_DEN_R = 0xC0;    // Enable Port B for I2C module 6

    SYSCTL_RCGCI2C_R = (1 << 4) | (1 << 6);  // Mode Clock Gating Control for I2C modules 4 and 6
    GPIO_PORTK_AFSEL_R = 0xC0;      // Alternate Function Select PK6, PK7
    GPIO_PORTB_AHB_AFSEL_R = 0xC0;  // Alternate Function Select PB6, PB7
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PK6_I2C4SCL);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PK7_I2C4SDA);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB6_I2C6SCL);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB7_I2C6SDA);

    GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, 7);       // Configurtes SDA
    GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, 6);    // Configurtes SCL
    GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, 7);       // Configurtes SDA
    GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, 6);    // Configurtes SCL

    I2CMasterInitExpClk(I2C4_BASE, SysCtlClockGet(), false);

    I2CSlaveEnable(I2C6_BASE);
    I2CSlaveInit(I2C6_BASE, SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C4_BASE, SLAVE_ADDRESS, false);
    //
    // Loop forever.
    //
    while(1)
    {
        //
        // Turn on the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R |= 0x8;

        I2CMasterDataPut(I2C4_BASE, 0x33);
        I2CMasterControl(I2C4_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_SINGLE_SEND);
        //
        // Wait until the slave has received and acknowledged the data.
        //
        while(!(I2CSlaveStatus(I2C6_BASE) & I2C_SLAVE_ACT_RREQ));
        //
        // Read the data from the slave.
        //
        result = I2CSlaveDataGet(I2C6_BASE);
        //
        // Wait until master module is done transferring.
        //
        while(I2CMasterBusy(I2C4_BASE));
        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        delay ();
        //
        // Turn off the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R &= ~(0x8);
        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        delay ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put pull-up resistors on the I2C lines? I2C is an open-collector signalling system, so the bus needs pull-up resistors to function. For your test, you can probably enable the GPIO's internal pull-ups if available.

Comment: A procedure GPIOPinTypeI2C() switches internal pull up resistor on, but a SDA line is waiting in High level. The problem is according to me on SCL side.

Comment: What about function `GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL`? It is called for the two SCL pins (master/slave). That may explain why SDA is okay, but SCL is not.

Comment: If these functions are polled, then you may not be able to do this the way you would like. The I2C slave may be clock stretching until you call the `I2CSlaveDataGet` function, but your code may be blocked on one of the earlier I2C master calls which are waiting to be able to send. I am not familiar enough with this part's I2C driver to be able to diagnose if that's the issue.

Comment: According to Peripheral Driver Library USER’S GUIDE
GPIOPinTypeI2C
Description:
The I2C pins must be properly configured for the I2C peripheral to function correctly. This function provides the proper configuration for the SDA pin. 

GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL
Description:
The I2C pins must be properly configured for the I2C peripheral to function correctly. This
function provides the proper configuration for the SCL pin.

Comment: The procedure get stuck at while(!(I2CSlaveStatus(I2C6_BASE) & I2C_SLAVE_ACT_RREQ)); But you are right with the clock stretching but it is at Low level.

Comment: Also take into account that software accuracy for I2C operating is important very much. I2C is a capricious bus and the devices are too. If you say push wrong address to the BUS and no slave answers then at you master side it is some of error state and it is immediately stuck in somewhere until the status/errors are processed properly. Just be aware of things like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. There were issues:

- It is essential to populate external pull ups.
- Use `GPIOPinTypeI2C()` 2nd parameter as a bit field instead of a bit number.
- The procedure `SysCtlClockSet()` is dedicated specially to TM4C123 devices. Instead use `g_ui32SysClock = SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_320), 40000000);`
- For a Master clock setting do not use `SysCtlClockGet()` procedure. This is also dedicated to TM4C123 devices. Instead use `I2CMasterInitExpClk(I2C4_BASE, g_ui32SysClock, false);`

Here is the updated code,

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_i2c.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/i2c.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "inc/tm4c129xnczad.h"

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x3C

void    delay   (void)
{
  volatile uint32_t ui32Loop;   
    for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 200; ui32Loop++);
}


volatile uint32_t  result;
    uint32_t    g_ui32SysClock;

int main(void)
{
    g_ui32SysClock = SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_320), 40000000); 
    //
    // Enable the GPIO port that is used for the on-board LED.
    //
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R3 | SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R9 | SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R1;
    //
    // Do a dummy read to insert a few cycles after enabling the peripheral.
    //
    result = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R;
    //
    // Enable the GPIO pin for the LED (PD3).  Set the direction as output, and
    // enable the GPIO pin for digital function.
    //
    GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DIR_R = 0x8;
    GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DEN_R = 0x8;

    SYSCTL_RCGCI2C_R = (1 << 4) | (1 << 6); // Mode Clock Gating Control for I2C modules 4 and 6

    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PK6_I2C4SCL);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PK7_I2C4SDA);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB6_I2C6SCL);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB7_I2C6SDA);

    GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, (1 << 7));       // Configures SDA
    GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, (1 << 6));    // Configures SCL
    GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, (1 << 7));       // Configures SDA
    GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, (1 << 6));    // Configures SCL

    I2CMasterInitExpClk(I2C4_BASE, g_ui32SysClock, false);

    I2CSlaveEnable(I2C6_BASE);
    I2CSlaveInit(I2C6_BASE, SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C4_BASE, SLAVE_ADDRESS, false);
    //
    // Loop forever.
    //
    while(1)
    {
        //
        // Turn on the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R |= 0x8;

        I2CMasterDataPut(I2C4_BASE, 0x33);
        I2CMasterControl(I2C4_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_SINGLE_SEND);
        //
        // Wait until the slave has received and acknowledged the data.
        //
        while(!(I2CSlaveStatus(I2C6_BASE) & I2C_SLAVE_ACT_RREQ));           
        //
        // Read the data from the slave.
        //
        result = I2CSlaveDataGet(I2C6_BASE);
        //
        // Wait until master module is done transferring.
        //
        while(I2CMasterBusy(I2C4_BASE));
        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        delay   ();
        //
        // Turn off the LED.
        //
        GPIO_PORTD_AHB_DATA_R &= ~(0x8);
        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        delay   ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get I2C working on TIVA Launchpad TM4C123GH6PM. I used the the Tivaware library. I created 3 functions, init and write. Here are the functions.

**Initialization**

```
void initI2C0(void)
{
   SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_I2C0);

   //reset I2C module
   SysCtlPeripheralReset(SYSCTL_PERIPH_I2C0);

   //enable GPIO peripheral that contains I2C
   SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOB);

   // Configure the pin muxing for I2C0 functions on port B2 and B3.
   GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB2_I2C0SCL);
   GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB3_I2C0SDA);

   // Select the I2C function for these pins.
   GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
   GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);

   // Enable and initialize the I2C0 master module.  Use the system clock for
   // the I2C0 module.  The last parameter sets the I2C data transfer rate.
   // If false the data rate is set to 100kbps and if true the data rate will
   // be set to 400kbps.
   I2CMasterInitExpClk(I2C0_BASE, SysCtlClockGet(), false);

   //clear I2C FIFOs
   HWREG(I2C0_BASE + I2C_O_FIFOCTL) = 80008000;
}
```

**I2C Write Function**

```
void writeI2C0(uint16_t device_address, uint16_t device_register, uint8_t device_data)
{
   //specify that we want to communicate to device address with an intended write to bus
   I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C0_BASE, device_address, false);

   //register to be read
   I2CMasterDataPut(I2C0_BASE, device_register);

   //send control byte and register address byte to slave device
   I2CMasterControl(I2C0_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_SEND_START);

   //wait for MCU to finish transaction
   while(I2CMasterBusy(I2C0_BASE));

   I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C0_BASE, device_address, true);

   //specify data to be written to the above mentioned device_register
   I2CMasterDataPut(I2C0_BASE, device_data);

   //wait while checking for MCU to complete the transaction
   I2CMasterControl(I2C0_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_RECEIVE_FINISH);

   //wait for MCU & device to complete transaction
   while(I2CMasterBusy(I2C0_BASE));
}
```

Complete code for TIVA + I2C can be found [here](https://github.com/mahengunawardena/Tiva_I2C_Nokia_ADXL345).

**Reference**

- [I2C Communication with the TI Tiva TM4C123GXL](https://www.eewiki.net/display/microcontroller/I2C+Communication+with+the+TI+Tiva+TM4C123GXL#I2CCommunicationwiththeTITivaTM4C123GXL-ExampleofGenericI2CCommunications)

Comment: @Parag The code word as it is, why do you want to change the code. The complete code is on github